# Timer cannot restart after it is being stopped in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, python-multithreading

I am using Python 2.7. I have a timer that keeps repeating a timer callback action until it has been stopped. It uses a Timer object. The problem is that after it has been stopped, it cannot be restarted. The Timer object code is as follows;

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatingTimer(object):
    def __init__(self,interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RepeatingTimer, self).__init__()
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.function = function
        self.interval = interval

    def start(self):
        self.callback()

    def stop(self):
        self.interval = False       

    def callback(self):
        if self.interval:
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            Timer(self.interval, self.callback, ).start()
```

To start the timer, the code below is run;

```
repeat_timer = RepeatingTimer(interval_timer_sec, timer_function, arg1, arg2)
repeat_timer.start()
```

To stop the timer, the code is;

```
repeat_timer.stop()
```

After it is stopped, I tried to restart the timer by calling `repeat_timer.start()` but the timer is unable to start. How can the timer be made to restart after it has been stopped?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a corrected version:

```
from __future__ import print_function


from threading import Timer


def hello():
    print("Hello World!")


class RepeatingTimer(object):

    def __init__(self, interval, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.interval = interval
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.timer = None

    def callback(self):
        self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.timer.cancel()

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Timer(self.interval, self.callback)
        self.timer.start()


t = RepeatingTimer(3, hello)
t.start()
```

**Example Run:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
>>> Hello World!

>>> Hello World!

>>> t.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code works. I am trying to understand why it works. Please be patient with me. Inside `def callback(self):`, why do you need the  `finally:
            self.start()`? What is the difference between the old code and your code which works?

Comment: Sorry the ``try/finally`` in ``def callback(self):`` is probably not necessary. Updated the code sample :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your timer is not restarting is because you never reset `self.interval` to `True` before trying to restart the timer.  However, if that's the only change you make, you will find your timer is vulnerable to a race condition that will result in more than one timer running concurrently.