# Python timer that can be postponed / extended?

Tags: python, timer

In the following code, I try to call a function when `do_it()` has not been called for 0.9s. However, I keep creating new timer and cancelling it. Is there a way to create just 1 timer thread and keep on postponing it?

```
def expired():
    print "Expired"

t = None
def do_it():
    global t
    print "tick", time.time()
    if t:
        t.cancel()
    t = threading.Timer(0.9, expired)
    t.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(random.random())
    do_it()
```

Comment: It seems you have to create a new timer class. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072765/timer-cannot-restart-after-it-is-being-stopped-in-python

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The example seems to be restarting a timer after it expired. Technically speaking, it is not restart, it is starting a new one. I am trying to avoid exactly that.

Comment: My point is that the `Timer` class doesn't have a `restart` method (you can check the source code), so either you make one in a new class (which technically is a cancelation with a restart in the example shown) or keep your current code.