# How to update object configuration periodically?

Tags: python, multithreading

I`m writing a connector to our CRM system. CRM has its own configurations I want to be aware of. CRM is the only source of trust for these configurations and provides them via an API. Now I have my connector in python package as a python class. CRM configurations are updated on **init**, but as soon as they can be changed from CRM I want them to be periodically updated. Is there any good way to create some kind of task on object instance creation to perform configuration updates?

```
class Crm:
    def __init__(self, crm_config, mongo_connection_string):
        self.update_crm_configuration()

    def update_crm_configuration(self):
        self.crm_configuration = self.get_crm_configuration_from_crm_api()

    def get_crm_configuration_from_crm_api(self):
        r = self._send_crm_request_wrap(send_request_func=self._send_get_crm_configuration)
        return self._parse_crm_configuration_response(r.text)
```

Now I update configurations one time, but I need to update them periodically.

Comment: You can take a look at [crontab](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) or use a restarting timer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072850/3767239).

Comment: The main issue with threading for this problem is that you cannot pass object instance as a parameter for another thread and thus you cannot simply update the object calling its own function. I believe some tricky object serialization can help, but obviously, it is not an easy and transparent solution.

Comment: Of course you can, with threading there's no problem, only for multiprocessing you would need serialization. For example [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) you can pass `args=...` which will be arguments to the threaded function.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the best way is not to use a different thread or task with periodic updates, but save last time the configuration was updated and if this time exits some timeout update the configuration before actually performing the request.

Or if your API has the luxury of good exceptions for the "Configuration was changed" it is even better to perform the configuration update on response handler before the request retry.

I`m using a request wrapper for these purposes.

```
    def _send_crm_request_wrap(self, send_request_func, func_params=(),
                               check_crm_configuration=True,
                               retries_limit=None):
        if check_crm_configuration \
                and time.time() - self.last_update_crm_configuration_time > CRM_CONFIGURATION_TIMEOUT:
            self.update_crm_configuration()

        while self.is_crm_locked():
            time.sleep(1000)

        if not self.is_authorized():
            self.auth()

        r = send_request_func(*func_params)
        if retries_limit is None:
            retries_limit = self.max_retries
        retry = 1
        while r.status_code == 205 and retry <= retries_limit:
            waiting_time = randint(1000, 2000)
            logging.info(f'Retry {retry} for {send_request_func.__name__}. Waiting for {waiting_time} sec')
            time.sleep(waiting_time)
            r = send_request_func(*func_params)
            retry += 1

        if r.status_code not in [200]:
            message = f'AMO CRM {send_request_func.__name__} with args={func_params} failed. ' \
                      f'Error: {r.status_code} {r.text}'
            logging.error(message)
            raise ConnectionError(message)

        return r
```